# Сколько времени прошло

Tags: время, php

Риторический вопрос, конечно, но своего ответа я так и не нашел.

```
$t = "03:40:50";
$date = time('H:i:s') - $t;
echo $date;
```

Вопрос: как так отнять?

Comment: глядя на заголовок вопроса, так и тянет продолжить "а он всё тот же"

Comment: @DreamChild, Зато мы все к нему уже привыкли, хорошо что он такой есть.

Answer (score 3):

```
$t = new DateTime('03:40:50');
$date = new DateTime();
$interval = $date->diff($t);
echo $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Comment: на часах 3:45:10
$t = mktime(3, 50, 50);

02:53:59

показывает.

Comment: @big-vl, Изменил ответ, так точно должно работать. Плюс, вместо строки в explode можно поставить другой вывод функции date, или время из БД.

Comment: спасибо то что нужно!!!

Хотя нет мне нужно время которое осталось! разница как бы...
Надпись к примеру до запуска ракеты осталось 00час:24мин:10сек слова не нужны

Comment: щас он че то показывает 23 часа, хотя я понял он всего лишь отнимает время назад.

Comment: @big-vl ваши волшебные слова - [php countdown](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+countdown)

Comment: @big-vl, в вашем примере, если бы он работал, никак не могло показываться оставшееся время, там именно отнимается ваше время от текущего.
@eicto, спасибо, а то у меня уже мозги кипеть начали.

Comment: @big-vl, изменил ответ. Вот вам ваш интервал.

Comment: Это хороший ответ.

Answer (score 3):

как-то видимо так:

```
$t = strtotime('03:40:50'); //секунды
$diff = time() - $t; //разница в секундах
echo date('H:i:s', $diff); //вывод формата
```

т.е. если покороче, то

```
echo date('H:i:s', time() - strtotime('03:40:50'));
```

Comment: @zippp, да не разница там будет а вычитание указанного количества секунд из метки времени. И зачем этот изврат с умножением на 60? Почитайте документацию. к date().

Comment: к минусующим большая просьба, комментируйте

Comment: @zippp, я минусовал. Уже снял, ибо откровенный трэш вы убрали.

Comment: треш был в том чтобы человеку показать что в секунды переводится его время, почему-то думал что так будет подоходчивей, но потом передумал и начал редактировать :) после чего увидел -1